# the drop event is not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery

am working on a project using jquery,where we have to drag one div and drop on to the   map. it is working but 1st wee have to click somewhere in the page then the div is got selected else it will not select and unable to drop..

```
 render: function(){
var leftMatrixTemplate = _.template(Application.Template.Maps.LeftMatrix, {});
$("#left-navigation").html(leftMatrixTemplate).removeClass("hidden");
var detailedViewTemplate = _.template(Application.Template.Maps.DetailedView, {});
$(this.el).html(detailedViewTemplate).removeClass("hidden");
$('div[id^="cu-"]').on('dragstart',function(e){
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("Text",e.currentTarget.id);
});
$('div[id^="lum-"]').on('dragstart',function(e){
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("Text",e.currentTarget.id);
});
$('#MapView').on('drop',function(e){
    var x = e.originalEvent.clientX + $(this).scrollLeft() - this.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.originalEvent.clientY + $(this).scrollTop() - this.offsetTop;
    e.originalEvent.stopPropagation();
    e.originalEvent.preventDefault();
    var data = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var did = 'd'+data;
    if (data.match("^cu")){
        $(this).append('<div class="dropped cuImg" id="'+did+'"></div>');
    }else{
        $(this).append('<div class="dropped luminaryImg" id="'+did+'"></div>');
    }
    $('#'+did).css('left',x).css('top',y);
}).on('dragover', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

}

please help me to come out from this,, thankq

Comment: you should replicate your issue on jsfiddle

Comment: Link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)